# Firebase cloud function cannot deploy functions that call a separate local function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In the context of the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/?authuser=0#partial_deploys

Inside `functions/index.js` we have

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.groupA = {
  function1: functions.https.onRequest(...);
  function2: functions.database.ref('\path').onWrite(...);
}
exports.groupB = require('./groupB);
```

Then inside `functions/groupB.js` we have:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.function3 = functions.storage.object().onChange(...);
exports.function4 = functions.analytics.event('in_app_purchase').onLog(...);
```

However, in my case inside `groupB.js` I have another `exports.function5` that calls another function `local_function` insdie groupB.js

```
exports.function5 = admin.database.ref(....).onCreate(
event=>{
return local_function()
})

function local_function()
{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
...
}
}
```

This failed to deploy to the cloud functions.

Comment: With what exact error code? Have you tried it multiple times?

Comment: ⚠  functions: failed to create function FUNCTION_NAME
⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
Yes, multiple times.

Comment: So if you replace `return local_function` with `return 1` there is no error?

Comment: Actually, after I changed the name of the function everything started to work. So the local function isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make sense:

```
exports.function5 = admin.database.ref(....).onCreate(event=>{
    return local_function
})
```

It's returning a function, which is not helpful for Cloud Functions.  I think you likely meant to return the result of the calling `local_function`:

```
exports.function5 = admin.database.ref(....).onCreate(event=>{
    return local_function()
})
```

This should invoke `local_function` and return the promise that it returns.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I meant to return a promise.. The deployment issue ended up being fixed by renaming the function.. Thank you.